# How to Find Unique Row and sum that all product VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel

**How to Find Unique Row and sum that all product VBA Code**

There are 8 Rows with Order Number and Value information. If there are duplicates based on fields in column A then I want to sum the amounts in column F and E and just keep 1 entry/row for it.Therefor i need VBa code for the same

Right Now I am not able to upload picture because i have not earn badge of this site I will give example above

if possible but i don't know how to use it Can anyone help????? I would greatly appreciate it!!

Comment: still not clear, but i think you don't even need vba. please update your question, without trying to be brief

Comment: hi @milevyo above is my question this is done by vba code

Comment: Hi,
I have over 2000 records. Need code to 
check duplicate row ("A") then
sum ("E")
and delete row.

example 
A B C D E 
1|4 6
2|5 9
3|4 3
4|6 5
5|4 2

After code should look thus

A B C D E 
1|4 11
2|5 9
3|6 5     I hope you understand @milevyo

Comment: question too vague... more info needed... please be specific, 8 rows or 2000 records? you can use excel-formula to find duplicates in a column. and what do u mean just keep 1 entry/row for it?

Comment: You can upload a picture(or wb) to your google drive then supply a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i 50% understood your query :)

let's see

```
   A    B   E
1| 4    6   
2| 5    9   
3| 4    3   
4| 6    5   
5| 4    2
```

to this

```
   A    B   E
1| 4    ?   11
2| 5    ?   9
4| 6    ?   5
```

it is a kind of `=Select sum(B:B) group by (A:A)`

i still don't know why E and not (C & D), but here is what you have to do

in cell E1 type `[=SUMIF(A:A;"="&A1;B:B)]`, this will sums [B:B] grouping by [A:A]

the result will be:

```
   A    B   E
1| 4    6   11
2| 5    9   9
3| 4    3   11
4| 6    5   5
5| 4    2   11
```

now you have to remove duplication. (in office 2010 and above i believe there is a [command for that](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/remove-duplicates.html)) but if you don't have it, you can do this steps

```
   *ensure that the first row is the header row , this is needed by formulas on step 3, and for sorting

   1) make [E:E] static*
   2) Sort the table on column A:A
   3) in cell [F2] put [=A2=A1], (true if current cell equals previous cell, otherwise false)
   3) copy paste formulas on the rest of the rows [F:F] starting from the next cell down to the last cell
   3) make [F:F] static*
   4) sort the table by column [F:F]
   5) delete All rows where cell [F?] have value of [true]
   6) delete the column [F:F], not needed any more
   7) column [B:B] is no more needed either
   8) done
```

you will end by this:

```
   before deletion:
        A   B   E   F
   1|   4   6   11  FALSE
   2|   4   3   11  TRUE
   3|   4   2   11  TRUE
   4|   5   9   9   FALSE
   5|   6   5   5   FALSE


   after deletion:
        A   B   E   F
   1|   4   6   11  FALSE
   2|   5   9   9   FALSE
   3|   6   5   5   FALSE
```

> **Make cell static?**
>
> copy cell then paste its values on it self overwriting its formulas, so that when you delete rows, or sort columns values won't change

Comment: @Ajay, i posted my answer as i understood your question, and you have been here about 6 hours already, but you didn't left any comment.

Comment: Thanks @milevyo i got it